# Including and using Zend Service ReCaptcha in ZF2 (v2.3.3)

Tags: forms, zend-framework2, recaptcha, zend-form2

how to include Recaptcha service in zend framework 2?

I tried to do like this:

```
public function contactAction()
{
    $formContact = new ContactForm();
    $pubKey = 'mypubkey';
    $privKey = 'myprivkey';
    $recaptcha = new ZendService\ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($pubKey, $privKey);
    return array ('formContact' => $formContact, 'recaptcha' => $recaptcha);

}
```

but I discovered that ZendService\ReCaptcha is not present by default when you download the framework. 
So, I downloaded it from here 
https://github.com/zendframework/ZendService_ReCaptcha

and I placed it into `vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\zend` together with the other parts of the library.

I tried to refresh the page but doesn't work again because it can't find the zend service recaptcha.

```
Fatal error: Class 'Application\Controller\ZendService\ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\xampp\htdocs\Zf-tutorial\module\Application\src\Application\Controller\IndexController.php on line 79
```

can someone help me? I thought it was simple to implement recaptcha, but it is not so ! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the zendservice-recaptcha module to your composer.json file and run an update:

```
{
        ...
        "repositories": [
            {
                "type": "composer",
                "url": "http://packages.zendframework.com/"
            }
        ],
        ...
        "require": {
            ...
            "zendframework/zendservice-recaptcha": "*",
            ...
        }
        ...
    }
```

update composer :

```
php composer.phar update
```

This will install the module and configure the relevant class mapping and you will be able to access the classes by adding the use statements as with any other classes you use.

Answer (score 0):

Even i tried **recaptcha** but with no success so implemented something different to refresh **captcha** and  worked very well, try this once

*resetCaptcha function*:

```
    $form = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('zfcuser_register_form');
    $captcha = $form->get('captcha')->getCaptcha();
    $data = array();
    $data['id'] = $captcha->generate();
    $data['src'] = $captcha->getImgUrl() .
    $captcha->getId() .
    $captcha->getSuffix();
    return $data;
```

*ajax request :*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#refreshcaptcha').click(function() {
            var data = [];
            var form = <?php $this->registerForm; ?>
            data.push({name: "action", value: 'resetCaptcha'});
            data.push({name: "params[form]", value: form});
            $.post("<?php echo BASE_URL ?>/user/iajax", data,
               function(data) {
                        $('#form_reg img').attr('src', data.src);
                        $('#captcha-id-hidden').attr('value', data.id);
                    }, 'json');
        });
    });
```

**Html call :**

```
   <p class="refresh_captcha"><?php echo $this->formCaptcha($form->get('captcha')); ?>
                <input type="button" id="refreshcaptcha" value="refresh">
            </p>
```

Answer (score -1):

You do not properly install the library `ZendService\ReCaptcha`.

your system write:

`Class 'Application\Controller\ZendService\ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha' not found`

**You must:**

- placed it into `vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library`
- In the file `vendor/ZF2/library/Zend/Loader/StandardAutoloader.php` insert string

  `$this->registerNamespace('ZendService', dirname(dirname((__DIR__)))
  . '/ZendService');`

  in `case self::AUTOREGISTER_ZF:`
- in the file `init_autoloader.php` insert string

  `$loader->add('ZendService', $zf2Path);`.

Comment: You obviously didn't know what a Composer is.